# Using if statement in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, if-statement

I'm new to GEE and and having problems to create an if statement with .contains().

Using I let the user create a point in the map using onClick. I have a polygon layer with fire areas. If the point is within the polygon I want to change a text in my panel probably using text.set({value: 'evacuate'}) and if not, nothing changes.

I've been trying to use the ee.Algorithms.If() but doesn't really know how it works. I probably don't know how the .contains() works either.

My code:

```
 var text_containsfire = ee.Algorithms.If(closest_fires.contains(point), title2.set({value:'Evacuate'}), print('check if false'));
 print('activate', text_containsfire);
```

closest_brandomrade is the fire polygon as .geometry().

point generated from onClick.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are in the correct way, but the returning result of the if statement should be of the same type. For the `true` case you are setting a value of a dictionary, and for the `false` case you are printing a value (not allowed since `print` does not return anything). Here is an example:

```js
var geometry = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
    [[[-72, -41],
      [-72, -44],
      [-70, -44],
      [-70, -42]]]);

var geometry2 = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[-72, -42],
          [-72, -42.5],
          [-69, -42.5],
          [-69, -42]]]);

Map.addLayer(geometry)
Map.addLayer(geometry2)

// Callback function for onClick Map method
var callback = function(coords) {
  // Output dict
  var output = ee.Dictionary({message:'Safe zone'})

  // Create point from coords
  var point = ee.Geometry.Point([coords.lon, coords.lat])

  // conditions (geometry contains point?)
  var condition1 = geometry.contains(point)
  var condition2 = geometry2.contains(point)

  // Create a message using a conditional if statement
  // condition 1
  output = ee.Dictionary(ee.Algorithms.If(condition1, output.set('message', 'Evacuate'), output))
  // condition 2
  output = ee.Dictionary(ee.Algorithms.If(condition2, output, output.set('message', 'Dange area')))

  // Do whatever with the message
  print(output.get('message'))
}

Map.onClick(callback)
```

link: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9364940c5fe878e75ede9b5b98b2c6de

Comment: Great @Rodrigo. 
I got it working by using this code (See line 122-154):
[link] (https://code.earthengine.google.com/229a30982079d7cb9a0e1768d403835b)
However, I'm now struggling with the false statement. I have 4 different buffer zones and the last one is overwriting the previous ones. I get true on zone 1 which should add its text but the zone 4 function is overwriting it with its false statement so that text is the output. Any solutions?

Comment: you could do something like this: https://code.earthengine.google.com/9364940c5fe878e75ede9b5b98b2c6de. If it suits you, tell me and I update the answer

Comment: Thanks @Rodrigo that was just what I needed for it to work the way I wanted. 
I added the following code in order to update my panel with the output text (if it would be of interest for someone in the future)
`var text_string = ee.String(output.get('message'));
  var update_paneltitle = title2.set({value: text_string.getInfo()});`